# What option in indent would remove the space for cast even for private type?

Tags: c, indentation

I use indent tool to format my [c](/questions/tagged/c) code.

**From indent tool manual:**

> The ‘-ncs’ ensures that there is no space between the cast operator and the object. Remember that indent only knows about the standard C data types and so cannot recognise user-defined types in casts. Thus (mytype)thing is not treated as a cast.
>   https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_chapter/indent_1.html#SEC14

Now, how can I make indent tool to remove the space between private cast 
in

```
return (MY_TYPE) val;
```

to

```
return (MY_TYPE)val;
```

Comment: You could modify the the source of indent to recognize user defined types

Comment: I always found indent to be too limited to get the code exactly as you want it. You might want to try out [Universal Indent](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/) which offers several "code beautifiers" in one GUI.